# Получить строку с десятичной записью числа

Tags: c, строки

Добрый вечер. Задача состоит в том, чтобы ввести число и ввести систему счисления. И получиться строку содержащую десятичную запись числа.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    int a;
    char buffer[20];
    printf("Vvedite chislo\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    do
    {
        printf("Sistema schisleniya \n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        itoa(a,buffer,10);  
    }
    while(n>10 || n<0);
    printf("Chislo = %s\n", buffer);
    system ("pause");
    return 0;   
}
```

Вот код, но программа не совсем корректно работает. Я не могу найти ошибку. Как ее исправить?

Comment: "не совсем корректно работает" - опишите ввод и ожидаемый/получаемый вывод

Comment: @Igor Ввод числа в n системе счисления и ввод самой системы счисления. Результат: число в десятичной системе счисления

Comment: Вы в цикле пишете в `buffer` снова и снова, перезаписывая на каждой итерации всё, что в нём уже было.

Comment: У кого-то из нас трудности с русским языком. (Я даже догадываюсь - у кого.) - опишите ввод и ожидаемый/получаемый вывод

Comment: @Igor Vvedite chislo 10,
Vvedite sistemy schisleniya 4,
Chilso = 20233322302.

Ожидаю
Vvedite chislo 22,
Vvedite sistemy schisleniya 4,
Chilso = 10

Comment: Ничего себе - "не совсем" корректно!

Comment: @Igor Так, как исправить, то что я наделал

Comment: А вас не смущает то, что первый аргумент itoa - число, а вы ей передаете туда строку? А зачем вам тут цикл?

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов У меня задание, что строка содержит запись натурального числа в n ричной системе счисления. Цикл для того чтобы n было в пределах от 1 до 9.

Comment: @Serg функция о вашем задании знает ровным счетом ничего. Передавать ей строку вместо числа - странно. Ограничение на n в задании не упомянуто...

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов Так а что мне делать?

Comment: @Serg попробуйте подумать, что строка это не число.

Comment: void main(void)
{
 char st[10];
 char buffer[20];

 gets(st);
 itoa(st, buffer, 10);
}

В Студии даже не компилится, потому что неверный тип параметра у itoa. Так что не верится мне в "не совсем корректно работает", оно и работать-то не может

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов я в теме исправил код программы. Теперь при вводе 22 и системе счисления 4, результат все равно 22. Даже если я в функции itoa вместо 10 напишу n. И при вводе укажу число 22 и систему счисления 4. Выводит 112, а нужно 10

Comment: @Serg почитайте про систему счисления, в которой работает scanf

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов мне нужно получить десятичную запись числа. Как это сделать в моей задаче? Причем тут scanf

Comment: @Serg "scanf("%d",&a);" в приведенном вами же коде. Ну да, можно взять и написать в программе что угодно, и оно будет совсем не причем и не влиять на работу программы. Вы серьезно так думаете и все еще не хотите читать документацию на используемые функции?

Answer (score 3):

Стало больно смотреть на эту переписку в комментариях...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    for(char buf[256];printf("Value: "), gets_s(buf,256);)
    {
        // Считывание основания системы счисления
        unsigned int n = 0;
        printf("Base: ");
        scanf("%u",&n);
        while(getc(stdin) != '\n');
        if (n == 0) break;

        // Преобразование; проверки переполнения нет!
        unsigned long long val = 0;
        int ok = 1;
        for(char*c = buf;*c;++c)
        {
            unsigned int dig = 0;
            if (!isalnum(*c)) { ok = 0; break; }
            if (isdigit(*c)) dig = *c - '0'; else dig = toupper(*c)-'A'+10;
            if (dig >= n) { ok = 0; break; }
            val = val*n + dig;
        }
        if (ok) printf("%s_%d =  %llu_10\n\n",buf,n,val);
        else printf("Wrong input\n\n");
    }
}
```